# How to group each block's data together instead of being grouped by the their xpath?

Tags: python, scrapy

Let's say I'm scraping data from structure that looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <span class="name">$somename</span>
    <span class="email">$someemial</span>        
    <span class="phone">$phone</span>
</div>
```

The scrapy code that I'm using is something like:

```
d.add_xpath('name', '//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="name"]')
d.add_xpath('name', '//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="email"]')
d.add_xpath('name', '//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="phone"]')
```

The results I'm getting are grouped this way:

```
name1
name2
name3 and so on...

then:
email1
email2
email3 and so on...

and finally:
phone1
phone2
phone3 and so on...
```

The but what I want is to group the data like this:

```
name1
email1
phone1

name2
email2
phone2

name3
email3
phone3

and so on ...
```

How how can I do that with scrapy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a zipped variable for it. Something like this:

```
for sel in xpath('//body'):
    name = sel.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="name"]')
    email = sel.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="email"]')
    phone = sel.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="phone"]')
    result = zip(name, email, phone)
    for name, email, phone in result:
        item['name'] = name
        item['email'] = email
        item['phone'] = phone
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a python question. For this kinds of data structure the best way to accomplish this is by using dictionaries:

```
dictExample={}
dictExample['name']=sel.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="name"]')
dictExample['email']=sel.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="email"]')
dictExample['phone']=sel.xpath('//div[@id="main"]/span[@class="phone"]')
```

By doing `print dictExample` it will return the following results:

```
{'phone': '872934987', 'name': 'Rafael Alonso', 'email': 'example@example.com'}
```

Now if you want to have multiple dictionaries just append them into a list:

```
listExample=[]
for i in range(0,5):
    listExample.append(dictExample)
```